# Не передаётся файл на сервер, но ответ от сервера приходит

Tags: php, java, android, клиент-сервер, rest

Пробую передать файл на сервер (перепробовал кучу примеров — ни один не работает) — не получается, непонятно, в чём проблема.

Запускаю код на эмуляторе: указываю файл, который хочу загрузить на сервер, где лежит php-cкрипт, который принимает файл от девайса-клиента.

В результате запуска программы приходит ответ от сервера — код `"200"`, но в папке uploads файла нету. На сервере ставил даже `777` на папку и скрипт.

Что может быть не так? Или может пример кода не рабочий? 
Может, что изменилось при работе с сетью в Android? Использую `sdk 22` в `AndroidStudio v2.2`

[Урок](http://androidexample.com/)

**Сlient android java:**

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    // путь к серверу у меня свой ! - этот для примера
    upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });                      

                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                }
            }).start();        
        }
    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                }
            }); 

            return 0;

        }
        else
        {
            try { 

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                         + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

        } // End else block 
    } 
}
```

**Server script php:**

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: почему бы вам не использовать готовую библиотеку для запросов на сервер? например retrofit? и файлы передавать умеет

Comment: потому что  я хочу разобрать как работает  Soket прежде чем влазить в фреймворки ,как мне кажется если с этим простым примером не разобраться то там (в фреймворках )еще сложнее будет от недопонимания

Comment: Фреймворк намного легче. На то он и фреймворк. Там что вы пишете все реализовано

Comment: Вашим скриптом в текущей редакции можно загрузить `backdoor.php` - одумайтесь!

Comment: каким образом и как этому противостоять ?

Comment: @mtb, не удаляйте, пожалуйста, ваши вопросы просто так. Если вы сумели сами найти решение - опубликуйте его в ответе - ваши вопросы и ответы - общее достояние и могут пригодится кому-то ещё. Мы здесь собираем базу знаний, но не помогаем конкретным людям решать их личные проблемы

Comment: @sanmai, дак можно ограничить исполнение частично (подобно песочнице) или закрыть вообще в папке `uploads` и скрипты не будут выполняться, только текстовые или картинки, php выполняться не будет и выплюнет как текст..

Comment: @And Можно и нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала неплохо было бы проверить результат загрузки файла.

```
if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {...}
```

Возможные коды ошибок загрузки можно посмотреть в [документации](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)
Если результат загрузки `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`, то могу посоветовать указать абсолютный путь в `$file_path` вместо относительного.